# Synchronize (multi)selection between two listboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have two listboxes that are bound to the same data source (an array of file names). one listbox views the files as icons whereas the other views them as a list. Now I would like them to have the same selection. So, when I multiselect two or more files in one, the same files should be selected in the other as well. Is there a way to do this, *preferably in XAML*? I tried `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` and binding to `SelectedItem` but those only work for single selections.

```
<Listbox Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
    <Listbox.ItemTemplate>
        // View as list
    </Listbox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<Listbox Name="IconView" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
    <Listbox.ItemTemplate>
        // View as Icon grid
    </Listbox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

XAML

```
 <StackPanel>
        <ListBox Height="100" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem}" x:Name="listview"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Height="100" x:Name="itemview" SelectionMode="Multiple"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

ViewModel

```
    private ObservableCollection<MultipleSelection> listBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<MultipleSelection>();
            public ObservableCollection<MultipleSelection> ListBoxItems
            {
                get
                {
                    return listBoxItems;
                }
                set
                {
                    listBoxItems = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("ListBoxItems");
                }
            }

            private MultipleSelection selectedListItem;
            public MultipleSelection SelectedListItem
            {
                get
                {
                    return selectedListItem;
                }
                set
                {
              selectedListItem = value;
            var selectedItems = ListBoxItems.Where(x => x.IsSelected);
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedListItem");

                }
            }

public class MultipleSelection : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private string item;

            public string Item
            {
                get { return item; }
                set
                {
                    item = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
                }
            }

            private bool isSelected;

            public bool IsSelected
            {
                get { return isSelected; }
                set
                {
                    isSelected = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                }
            }
        }
```